# Laravel artisan command with sub methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

This is probably a really basic question, but something I don't grasp from the docs.

I know how to create and run Artisan commands from the console, and I know how to add arguments and options like this:

`artisan some:function {argument} {--option}`

But is there any way to add sub-methods within this call, ie:

```
artisan mycommand:foo
artisan mycommand:bar
```

I had assumed so (otherwise what is the colon even for?) and yet I can only find information relating to options and arguments in the docs.

Is this possible, and how do I handle these within my Artisan command class? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by sub methods?  Just define the same prefix for two separate commands.

Comment: I mean methods that are related as part of the same process. For example, a two step process that might involve something like `artisan mycommand:setup` and then `artisan mycommand:dothething` which I would prefer to handle within the same class. Is this not possible? Do I in this case have to create entirely separate classes (or use an 'argument' or 'option' to specify the difference instead)?

Comment: How does laravel handle it when you do `artisan make:controller` and `artisan make:seeder`, are these handled completely independently of each other?

Comment: Two separate classes.  Look up ControllerMakeCommand and SeederMakeCommand.  If they share functionality, use a trait or inheritance.

Comment: OK fine. Thanks. I guess the colon is just for decoration then

Comment: And grouping when you list commands.

Comment: What do you mean by grouping?

Comment: Type `artisan` and see how they are grouped when listed.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just involves two separate command classes that use the same prefix in $signature.  The prefix provides a way of grouping like-commands together.

If they share functionality, use a trait or inheritance, but commands should be defined in separate classes.

Comment: Thanks. ...and I can see there is another benefit of the colon as well. If have a command like `artisan mycommand:foo` and you run a command like `artisan mycommand:bar` which doesn't exist, the console asks you "*did you mean mycommand:foo?*". Nice.